# MySQL update tabel set count = count +1 concurrent issue

Tags: mysql, database, concurrency

I need to update a table and set the `VOTE_COUNT = VOTE_COUNT + 1` on each call, say I have 10,000 concurrent access to the database and execute the same statement at the same time:

`UPDATE VOTE SET VOTE_COUNT = VOTE_COUNT + 1;`

Will it be any concurrent issue which makes the result not equals to
10000? (initial count = 0)

Comment: Might depend on your underlying storage engine. For innodb I would say no, for myisam I would say yes.

Comment: Any reason why engine might affect this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Transaction handling or not. Also locking will be a point if there is no transaction handling. Which results in bad performance when its table locking.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the mysql/mariadb underlying storage engine you might have concurrency or performance problems.

The best would be to have an storage engine with transaction handling - so that you would not have concurrency problems.

For the case that you use a storage engine without transaction handling, than it depends on the locking (no, row or table based).

With no locking you could have concurrency problems, because two update statements could read a value at the same time, add 1 and store it back - so one (or more) update statements will get lost! Because they will all store back the same value.

When locking the table for each update, then things will get very slow for your concurrent update statements!

Comment: So InnoDB should be safe?

Comment: Yes innoDB should do the job. Is also always my personal first choice.